# How do I avoid nodejs vm script function call losing context when called function is itself in the context?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The problem: I'm using nodejs vm to run a supplied script (trusted source but not in my control).  The supplied script must call back to a function I provide in the context it receives.

Functions internal to the script work as expected.  But when a function supplied in the context is called, it no longer has any variables from the context provided to the called script.  This short program demonstrates the problem:

```
var vm = require('vm');
var sandbox={console:console, myfn:function() {
        console.log("MYFN");
        console.log("MYFN: a="+a);
}, a:42};
var ctx = new vm.createContext(sandbox);
vm.runInContext("function okfn() { console.log('OKFN'); console.log('OKFN: a='+a); } console.log('TEST'); console.log('TEST: a='+a);okfn(); myfn();", ctx, {filename:"TEST"});
```

When it runs, I expect to see output of:

```
TEST
TEST: a=42
OKFN
OKFN: a=42
MYFN
MYFN: a=42
```

but instead, the last console.log in myfn() produces a ReferenceError: a is not defined

Is there a way to retain the context passed to the script via runInContext(), when that script makes calls to a function provided in the context itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions are bound to the global scope in which they are defined. As `myfn` was defined in the main script file, it will use the globals of that file. In order to bind that function to another global context, it must be redefined/re-executed in that context:

```
var vm = require('vm');

function myfn() {
    console.log("MYFN");
    console.log("MYFN: a="+ a);
}


var sandbox={console:console, a:42};
var ctx = new vm.createContext(sandbox);

// Evaluates the source code of myfn in the new context
// This will ensure that myfn uses the global context of 'ctx'
vm.runInContext(myfn.toString(), ctx, {filename: "TEST"});

// Retained in the context
console.log(ctx.myfn);

// Use it
vm.runInContext("function okfn() { console.log('OKFN'); console.log('OKFN: a='+a); } console.log('TEST'); console.log('TEST: a='+a);okfn();  myfn();", ctx, {filename:"TEST"});
```